# Why setting object of "any" type to property with specific type doesn't throw TS compilation error?

Tags: typescript

Why this code is not throwing any Typescript errors (see [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ErrorData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20code%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EnrichedError%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20description%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20ErrorData%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20any%20%3D%20%22bla%20bla%20bla%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20EnrichedError%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20description%3A%20'this%20is%20a%20test'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20a%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)):

```
interface ErrorData {
    code: number;
    message: string;
}

interface EnrichedError {
    description: string;
    error: ErrorData;
}

const a: any = "bla bla bla";
const b: EnrichedError = {
    description: 'this is a test',
    error: a
}
```

**Why it's possible to set `b.error` to a?**

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the point of `any`, it is assignable to all types, and all types are assignable to it.

It is your escape hatch, it basically tells TypeScript that "this value can go anywhere"